# Flask can't running error after installing openssl with brew

Tags: python, openssl, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I installed openssl on my computer

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

If I want to run it with python or flask, I get an error like the one below.

```
FLASK_ENV=development python -m {APP_PATH}.wsgi
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  File "/Users/sumeyyeozkaynak/.virtualenvs/OptiwisdomSystemPants/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/_utils.py", line 21, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Users/sumeyyeozkaynak/.virtualenvs/OptiwisdomSystemPants/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what are you trying to achieve with flask and openssl here?

Comment: When I installed with "brew install openssl" I saw that it owerwrite python files. This prevented me from running python projects that I used flask. @Raiyan

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
When I installed with "brew install OpenSSL" I saw that it *overwrites python files*. This prevented me from running python projects that I used to flask.

I installed python with brew and I installed the virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper. I deleted all (python and virtualenvwrapper)

I installed **python and the virtual environment with pyenv**. My Flask project worked.